# How to mock TopicManagementResponse from firebase messaging in Junit using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase, junit, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to mock my TopicManagementResponse for testing my test class , but even after using `TopicManagementResponse resposne = Mockito.mock(TopicManagementResponse.class)` it still says resposne is null.

is this the correct way of mocking this class, or is there any way i can do this?

I am expecting to test class my class using TopicManagementResponse object . but its is null

my class :

```
@PostMapping("/subscribeToTopic")
    public int createTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) throws IOException, FirebaseMessagingException {
 
        String platformID = topic.getPlatformId();

        //my internal method to get firebase messaging app
        FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = fcmInitializer.getFirebaseMessaging(platformID);
 
        // Get the topic name from the "topic" field in the JSON
        String topicName = topic.getTopicName();
 
        // Check if the topic name is not null or empty
        if (topicName == null || topicName.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        TopicManagementResponse response = firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic.getToken(), topicName);
        return response.getSuccessCount();
 
    }
```

my Test class :

```
public void createTopic(){
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = mock(FirebaseMessaging.class);
    TopicManagementResponse response = mock(TopicManagementResponse.class);

    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setToken("some token");
    topic.setTopic("some topic");
    

    when(firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic.getToken(), topic.getTopic())).thenReturn(response);

    assertEquals(response.getSuccessCount, 1);


}
```

Comment: what version of `junit` are you using ? also you have to provide more reproducible example.

Comment: currently i am using junit 5

Comment: i have added a sample case where I am mocking this class

Comment: I wrote an answer where I gave you some hints and also a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension) about `Mockito` and `JUnit 5` your test class should be something like this one.

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class TestClass {
    
      @Mock
      private FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;
    
      @Mock
      private TopicManagementResponse response;
    
      @Test
      public void createTopic(){
    
        when(firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(response);
        when(response.getSuccessCount()).thenReturn(1);
    
        assertEquals(response.getSuccessCount(), 1);
        

  }
```

And also you will have to mock `fcmInitializer.getFirebaseMessaging()` based on your `createTopic` Controller method.